# How to make output showing true/false?

Tags: prolog

I am aiming for the program to print out `true` or `false` before returning to `menu2/0`

```
park(_,blue,basketball_court).

menu2 :- 
    nl,write('Select operation:'),nl,
    write('1. Check which parking area available to park right now.'),nl,
    write('2. Check whether a particular parking area is legal to park.'),nl,
    write('3. End program.'),nl,
    read(X),nl,choice(X).

choice(2):-
    write('Enter your identity:'),nl,
    read(C),
    write('Enter sticker type:'),nl,
    read(D),
    write('Enter parking area:'),nl,
    read(E),
    park(C,D,E),
    menu2.
```

Below is what I get:

```
menu2.

Select operation:
1. Check which parking area available to park right now.
2. Check whether a particular parking area is legal to park.
3. End program.
2

Enter your identity:
staff
Enter sticker type:
blue
Enter parking area:
basketball_court

Select operation:
1. Check which parking area available to park right now.
2. Check whether a particular parking area is legal to park.
3. End program.
```

After `basketball_court`, I am hoping for `True` to appear. Also, in another scenario, even if 'False' appear, how to make it loop back to `menu2/0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

```
choice(2):-
    write('Enter your identity:'),nl,
    read(C),
    write('Enter sticker type:'),nl,
    read(D),
    write('Enter parking area:'),nl,
    read(E),
    ( park(C,D,E) ->
      write('true'),nl
    ; write('false'),nl ),
    menu2.
```