# How to allow program to proceed?

Tags: prolog

How to make the program proceed to `menu1/0` after `false` appear

```
mylist([a,b,c]).
myprog(X) :- mylist(L), member(X, L).

go :- start_message,menu1.

start_message :- 
    write('This is a program.'),nl,
    write('Below are a list:'),nl,
    myprog(X), 
    write(X),nl, 
    fail.

menu1 :-
    nl,write('Select operation:'),nl,
    write('1. Input time'),nl,
    write('2. Exit program'),nl.
```

Below is what I am stuck with:

```
go.
This is a program.
Below are a list:
a
b
c
false
```

Comment: You could check [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47877534/how-to-make-output-showing-true-false) for how to use if-then-else.

Comment: well from `go :- start_message,menu1`?
but i will refer to if-then-else... that should be able to work.

Comment: I looked too quickly. The problem is that `start_message/0` just fails, so then `go/0` also fails.

Comment: @TomasBy I'm really sorry but still clueless about this.
`start_message :- 
    write('This is a program.'),nl,
    write('Below are a list:'),nl,
    myprog(X),
    write(X),nl, 
    ( fail -> 
     (menu1;go)).`
This is what I came up with but still doesn't work.

Comment: Putting `fail` in the condition is not useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
start_message :- 
    write('This is a program.'),nl,
    write('Below are a list:'),nl,
    ( myprog(X),
      write(X),nl, 
      fail
    ; true ).
```

Now when `myprog/1` cannot succeed anymore, control goes to `true/0` and `start_message/0` succeeds.

Comment: I see, I know what I have been having trouble with. Those build-in predicates...I have to learn more about them. Thanks, you have been giving me a great help!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `fail` statement in the last line of `start_message`.

Comment: Then you wouldn't get all the elements of the list.

Comment: yea i need to get all elements